# MTKView is unavailable on visionOS

Tags: xcode, metalkit, visionos

Working with Apple Vision Pro SDK. When trying to reference MTKView in MetalKit I get MTKView is unavailable in xrOS.

I am trying to run the ['Pipeline to Render Primitives'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/using_a_render_pipeline_to_render_primitives) code sample to discover MetalKit in VisionOS simulator. The MetalKit is available under visionOS in general but I see that [MTKView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtkview) is not specifically available. How can I run this sample code for visionOS? Is there different Metal sample code available for visionOS to try?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment [MTKView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtkview) is unsupported on visionOS – as you said it is clearly stated in the official documentation. So far, no SwiftUI view for Metal has been released. The short list of supported views is the following (`Xcode 15 beta 5`):

- Model3D
- [RealityView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76747287/what-is-the-difference-between-model3d-and-realityview-in-visionos/76747520#76747520)
- SceneView (2D)
- SpriteView
- Map
- WKWebView

Comment: *@Andy Jazz* thank you for the help. The actual problem that I want address is to gain full control over apple vision pros display and render 2d graph plot. Below is the question link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76715899/how-to-gain-full-control-over-apple-vision-pros-display-and-render-2d-graph-plo]