# How to gain full control over Apple Vision pro's display and render 2D graph plot on it

Tags: xcode, swiftui, metalkit, visionos, vision-pro

How can I achieve full control over Vision Pro's display and effectively render a 2D graph plot on it? I would appreciate guidance on the necessary steps or code snippets.

P.s. As per Apple documentation
**[*For a more immersive experience, an app can open a dedicated Full Space where only that app’s content will appear.*](https://developer.apple.com/visionos/)** This still does not fulfill the 'flat bounded 2D' requirement as the Spaces provides an unbounded 3D immersive view.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing is the new `CompositorServices` framework on visionOS, which let you render image for each eyes.

> Compositor Services lets you draw directly to the device’s displays using Metal and your own rendering engine. Use this framework to create a fully immersive scene in your app that doesn’t require integration with the person’s surroundings.

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compositorservices